# phpmyadmin not showing theme images

Tags: permissions, phpmyadmin

I just installed phpmyadmin on my local machine. However, the images for any of the buttons are not showing up. I tried installed a new theme, same thing. When I go to the images folder, they are all there.

I read one post where a user had to allow proper read permissions through IIS. I've beenn clicking permissions, but I think I'm a bit lost as to finding the right setting.

Does that make sense to anyone? :)  - I am looking for step by step instructions on giving the proper read permissions so that the images can display when I load phpmyadmin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this issue, it has to do with allowing IIS user permission to c:\temp, if that's where your PHP temp file folder is. You can check this by running phpinfo() from within a php file.

Unfortunately, I was messing with so many permissions, I'm not sure what exactly did it, I just know that it had to do with the temp folder.